# Laravel's Trait proper usage inside Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make my code more readable and reusable along my app.
I created for this purpose a Trait but I couldn't use it (probably I didn't understand the right way to import it).
My code is as follows:

Trait

```
    namespace App\Http\Traits;

use App\Models\FlightManagement\Aircraft;
use App\Models\FlightManagement\FunctionType;
use App\Models\FlightManagement\LogEntry;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

trait FlightTrait
{
    public function store_new_flight(Request $request, $log_entry)
    {
        $log_entry->aircraft_id = $request->aircraft_id;
        $log_entry->adep_id = $request->adep;
        $log_entry->ades_id = $request->ades;
        $log_entry->date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));
        $log_entry->atd = $request->atd;
        $log_entry->ata = $request->ata;
        $log_entry->operational_condition_id = $request->operational_condition_id;
        $log_entry->function_type_id = $request->function_type_id;
        $log_entry->instructor_id = $request->instructor_id;
        $log_entry->student_id = $request->student_id;
        $eet = date('H:i', (strtotime($request->ata)) - (strtotime($request->atd)));
        if ($request->ata <= $request->atd) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'ATA can not be greater or equal to ATD');
        }
        $function_type_obj = FunctionType::find($request->function_type_id)->name;
        if ($function_type_obj == 'Dual Command' and $request->instructor_id == '') {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Instructor Must be on Board!!!');
        }
        if ($function_type_obj == 'Single Pilot') {
            $log_entry->solo_flight = 1;
        }
        $aircraft_obj = $request->aircraft_id;
        $aircraft_type_obj = Aircraft::find($aircraft_obj)->aircraft_type->name;
        if ($aircraft_type_obj == 'MEP') {
            $log_entry->mep_flight = 1;
        }
        if ($aircraft_type_obj == 'SIM') {
            $log_entry->sim_flight = 1;
        }
        $log_entry->eet = $eet;
        $log_entry->save();
        return $log_entry;
    }

}
```

Basically my final goal is to use it inside a controller function as follows:

Controller

```
use App\Http\Traits\FlightTrait;

class LogEntryController extends Controller
{
   
    use FlightTrait;
    public function store_new_flight(Request $request)
    {
        $log_entry = new LogEntry();

        $log_entry->$this->store_new_flight($request, $log_entry);

        return redirect()->route('flight.list')->with('success', 'Flight Added Successfully');
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is likely to be in the way I call the trait function, but I googled around and I couldn't find anything.
The error is giving me is:

Error

```
Object of class App\Http\Controllers\FlightManagement\LogEntryController could not be converted to string
```

Comment: its just like calling any other method on the class as it is, traits are not special in the end they are just a 'mixin', as though you defined the method directly on the class ... this `$log_entry->$this->store_new_flight(...)` doesn't make sense [you want a property of `$log_entry` named the return value of `$this` which is an object?] .... just `$this->store_new_flight(...)`

Comment: Simply call as `$this->store_new_flight($request, $log_entry);`

Comment: If I call $this->store_new_flight($request, $log_entry) it gives me HTTP ERROR 500
 with Currently Unable To Handle This Request

Comment: and that is a different issue entirely now, as you are at least calling your method correctly now ... BTW your trait method isn't being applied to your class since you are defining a method with the same exact name directly on the class, you should probably read up on Precedence for traits ... https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.precedence Precedence

Comment: you have basically created a recursive loop (infinite loop) of the method calling itself, hence the 500 error